# Predict rating in content-based recommender

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, content-based-retrieval

I have been working with a basic CB rec sys and I already made this steps:

--Create TF-IDF vector for each item.
--Get user profile according to the ratings each user has given.

And after that it seems that I can just get the similarity between the user profile and the items features vectors which fine to recommend or get a ranking.
However, I need to compute a prediction for the rating because I will have to compare the results in terms of RMSE among different algorithms. In this case, I need a value (1 to 5) so I can calculate the error.
What would be the best formula to use?

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful to write answer when seeing the piece of your data

Comment: I am working with many datasets, all of them have ratings (user,item,ratings) and some item content. For example, the description of a book.